# Customized reference labels in biblatex / incremented shorthands

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

In writing a proposal, I'd like to have a way so that the references to my papers appear as `[XXn]` instead of `[n]`, where XX would be my initials and n the sorted or not counter.

Eventually, I'd possibly have two separate reference lists at the end, that of my works, and that of the other works.

I'd know how to do the second thing, using biblatex, I'm struggling with the first. Using a shorthand field doesn't produce increments.

Here is a MWE;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
  \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
      @article{A1,
        author = {myself},
        year = {2001},
        title = {A work of mine},
        shorthand = {XX},
        keywords={mine},
      }
      @article{A2,
        author = {myself},
        year = {2001},
        title = {A work of mine},
        shorthand = {XX},
        keywords={mine},
      }
      @article{B3,
        author = {Some random person},
        year = {2002},
        title = {Doing random things},
      }
      @article{B4,
        author = {Some other author},
        year = {2002},
        title = {Doing other things},
      }
  \end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
These are my works, \cite{A1,A2}. This is another one \cite{B3}, this as well, \cite{B4}, while this is mine and that of this other person \cite{A1,B3}

\printbibliography[title={Personnal publications},keyword=mine]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=mine]

\end{document}
```

This gives;
[image]

What I would want to have would be instead;

```
These are my works, [XX1,XX2]. This is another one [3], this as well, [4], while this is mine and that of this other person [XX1,4]
```

And the same labels in the reference section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `prefixnumbers` (it implicitly has a `resetnumbers`, but with your setup that doesn't matter)

```
\printbibliography[title={Personnal publications},keyword=mine,prefixnumbers={XX}]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=mine]
```

For good measure you should add `defernumbers=true` as `biblatex` option.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sorting=none,backend=biber,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
  \begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
      @article{A1,
        author = {myself},
        year = {2001},
        title = {A work of mine},
        keywords={mine},
      }
      @article{A2,
        author = {myself},
        year = {2001},
        title = {A work of mine},
        keywords={mine},
      }
      @article{B3,
        author = {Some random person},
        year = {2002},
        title = {Doing random things},
      }
      @article{B4,
        author = {Some other author},
        year = {2002},
        title = {Doing other things},
      }
  \end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
These are my works, \cite{A1,A2}. This is another one \cite{B3}, this as well, \cite{B4}, while this is mine and that of this other person \cite{A1,B3}

\printbibliography[title={Personnal publications},keyword=mine,prefixnumbers={XX}]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=mine]

\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

---

If you can't have the implicit `resetnumbers` try

```
\makeatletter
\define@key{blx@bib1}{prefixnumbersnoreset}{}
\define@key{blx@bib2}{prefixnumbersnoreset}{%
  \def\blx@prefixnumbers{#1}%
  \iftoggle{blx@defernumbers}
    {}
    {\iftoggle{blx@labelnumber}
       {\blx@warning{%
          Option 'prefixnumbers' requires global\MessageBreak
          'defernumbers=true'}}
       {}}}
\makeatother
```

with

```
\printbibliography[notkeyword=mine]
\printbibliography[title={Personnal publications},keyword=mine,prefixnumbersnoreset={XX}]
```